# Cannot ping router (from internet)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, ping

I can go to a "whatsmyip" site and it correctly reports the external IP of my router, however if I then try to get my girlfriend (who lives in another country) to ping that address, it doesn't work. I've also tried to ping the router from a variety of different "ping me" websites with no luck.

However, when I enable my VPN, the "whatsmyip" websites report the new address, and the "pingme" websites CAN ping the reported address.

What's going on? Even if I disable the firewall on my router, nothing is able to ping it.

Context: I'm trying to self-host a minecraft server, purely so that I can play online with me girlfriend. Been wrangling with this for hours

Comment: most routers by default do not allow ping. check your router settings. "pingme" web sites do not depend on ping - they usually check if port(s) are open. most routers will allow you to port forward traffic from Internet to a desired internal IP. read your routers documentation to see capabilities and how to configure it. do not forget that the firewall on your router is keeping you safe from many stuff.

Comment: A solution that many people use is Hamachi.  I only mention that if you are behind a double NAT configuration you wouldn’t be able to forward the required ports.  You don’t mention what subnet your public IP address is exactly.  While we don’t need to know your entire IP address the starting ocelot wouldn’t hurt.

Answer (score -2):

> I can go to a "whatsmyip" site and it correctly reports the external IP of my router

Sorry, that's not correct.  What you see is the translated address of your local devices.  That address is different than the IP address of the router interface.

When you browse the Internet, your router translates your internal, private IP of your PC (usually 192.168.0.x) to a public IP.  Your router remembers that translation for the duration of the browsing session -- when you leave the website, the translation is "forgotten" until you browse to a new site.

So if your girlfriend tries to ping your translated address, your router doesn't have the translation for your PC anymore.  So the ping is dropped.

What you need is a static translation for your Minecraft server.  Your ISP will give you one, if you ask -- and they will charge you for it.  then you would configure port forwarding on your router to translate the static IP to the address of the server.